# Jquery won't work in ASP.NET UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET **GridView** which has one column as a **link** - pushing the link fires a JQuery call and opens a fancybox.  Everything worked as intended until I moved my code within an **UpdatePanel**.

Once in the UpdatePanel, the link no longer works.   If I take everything out of the UpdatePanel, all works fine again.

How do I enable JQuery to recognize the GridView link from within the updatePanel?

```
            $("a.grid").click(function () {
            var ID = this.id;
            $.fancybox({
                'scrolling': true,
                'autoSize': false,
                'width': 1015,
                'height': 515,
                'transitionIn': 'fade',
                'transitionOut': 'fade',
                'speedIn': 200,
                'speedOut': 300,
                'type': 'iframe',
                'href': 'general_stats.aspx?ID=' + ID
            });
        });

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceGenStats1" Font-Size="Smaller" 
ForeColor="#4C98AA" GridLines="None" Width="669px" Visible="False">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PERSON_ID" HeaderText="Person ID" 
        SortExpression="PERSON_ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FIRST_NAME" HeaderText="First Name" 
        SortExpression="FIRST_NAME" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LAST_NAME" HeaderText="Last Name" 
        SortExpression="LAST_NAME" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Stats">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <a class="grid" id="<%# Eval("PERSON_ID") %>" href="#">View</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
<FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#4C98AA" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
    HorizontalAlign="Left" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
```

Comment: Javascript/jquery code will never be executed from ajax response(Your update panel).

Comment: are you using the <script></script> tag, rigth?

Answer (score 4):

You may need to register the call to bind to the click event handler with the PageRequestManager. More details can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028(v=vs.100).aspx

Something like this above the update panel:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(
  function() {
    $("a.grid").click(function () {
        var ID = this.id;
        $.fancybox({
            'scrolling': true,
            'autoSize': false,
            'width': 1015,
            'height': 515,
            'transitionIn': 'fade',
            'transitionOut': 'fade',
            'speedIn': 200,
            'speedOut': 300,
            'type': 'iframe',
            'href': 'general_stats.aspx?ID=' + ID
        });
    });
  }
);
});
```

Because of the post back, it's probably not loading the handler after a partial postback. This call will load the handler after a postback and async postback.

Comment: I tried both solutions.  This is what worked for me personally...at least with the least modification.  Thank you!

Comment: Still works in 2023. Tested in .NET Framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Sys.Applicaiton.add_load() event handler

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/534587/ASP-NET-jQuery-is-not-Working-in-UpdatePanels